# How come when I try to find the closest value to -1 in a BST, i get the wrong answer?

Tags: java, data-structures

i'm currently practicing my data structure skills and i ran across an issue. In this particular BST, whenever the target is -1, my code doesnt return the correct value. Its supposed to return the value in the BST that is closest in value to the requested target.

```
import java.lang.Math; 
class Program {
 public static int findClosestValueInBst(BST tree, int target) {
        int temp = tree.value;
        if(temp == target) {
            return temp;
        }
        while(tree.left != null || tree.right != null){
            if(tree.value < target){
                tree = tree.right;
            }
            else if(tree.value > target){
                tree = tree.left;
            }
            if(Math.abs(target - tree.value) < Math.abs(target - temp)){
                temp = tree.value;
            }
        }
        return temp;
 }
  static class BST {
    public int value;
    public BST left;
    public BST right;

    public BST(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Hoping someone here can lmk whats wrong.

I posted below the picture of the values that the BST is made up of.

[BST Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPcN.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You have (at least) four problems:

1. You update `tree` before updating `temp` (can cause NPE if you try to access `tree.value` before you know if it's `null` or not).
2. You don't check for exact matches along the way (can cause infinite loop).
3. If you end up traversing into a `null` element, you don't handle it properly (can cause NPE).
4. Your `tree.left != null || tree.right != null` check will prevent you from visiting any leaf nodes of the tree, because all leaf nodes have `null` as their right/left nodes.

Try this for your while loop:

```
while(tree != null) {
    if(Math.abs(target - tree.value) < Math.abs(target - temp)) {
        temp = tree.value;
    }
    if(tree.value < target) {
        tree = tree.right;
    }
    else if(tree.value > target) {
        tree = tree.left;
    }
    else {
        return target;
    }
}
```